# Add and destroy window in ViewModel

Tags: javascript, extjs, window, viewmodel

I have a ViewModel, which is empty, as the bind data is set dynamically elsewhere, which works fine -

```
Ext.define('TestApp.model.modelView', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
alias: 'viewmodel.test',
singleton: true

});
```

From my main view, I call a view on a button click, where I create a new window and display it

```
Ext.define('TestApp.view.main.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
xtype: 'app-main',

requires: [
     'TestApp.model.modelView'
],

viewModel: {
    type: 'test'
},

items: [
    {
        ...

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Read Out',
                margin: '5 10 0 10',
                handler: function () {
                    win = Ext.create('TestApp.view.ReadOutButtonTemplate');

                    TestApp.Controllers.ReadOutButtonController.windowOpened();
                }
            },
```

Here is the window layout

```
Ext.define('TestApp.view.ReadOutButtonTemplate', 
{
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
alias: 'roTemplate',
itemId: 'roWindow',

requires: [
     'TestApp.model.modelView'
],

viewModel: {
    type: 'test'
},

controller: 'roTemplate',
xtype:'buttonTemplate',

autoShow: true,
height: 600,
width: 600,
constrainHeader: true,
title: 'Window',
```

Each time I create a window, I want to add it to the model view, and each time I close a window, if I have multiple open, I only want to destroy the one the cross was clicked on, which I have attempted to reflect in -

```
listeners:{
    'close': function (win) {
        win.destroy();
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that each time I open a new window, it is creating a completely new ViewModel, which then when I destroy it, it is destroying the whole ViewModel, then not allowing me to use it for other windows that are still open, and in reality I want each window to be independent but using the same window template. Any help of thoughts on how to tackle this would be appreciated as I'm struggling to find any documentation on it.

Note - There are also controllers attached to the app, but these are working as I would expect.

Comment: Hi, a view model is attached to the view, so once you destroy the window it will destroy that view model. What you should do is have a parent view model that will hold the shared information.

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing me the right direction, after much research it was far simpler than I first thought creating a parents and child elements!

Comment: Im glad this worked, using viewModel.get() makes it really easy to loop cascade upwards from child to parent. Make sure you post your solution here so people with the same problem can see what you did :)